# Angular Material Table Does not Display Data

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to display data using a angular material table. But it's not display any data and does not log any error.i get my data by calling a service.

Html :-

```
 <div>
   <mat-table  #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="isbn">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ISBN </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.isbn}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="title">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.title}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="sector">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Sector </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.sector}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="pubDate">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Publication Date </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.pubDate}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="itemType">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Item Type </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.itemType}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let item; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
 </mat-table>
</div>
```

TypeScript :

```
export class DisplayAllitemsComponent implements OnInit {

       message:string;
      items:string[]=[];

      displayedColumns = ['isbn','title','sector','pubDate','itemType'];

      dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Item>;


      constructor(private appService: AppService) {
          this.appService.getAllItems()
           .subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
            console.log(this.dataSource)
           });
     }

  }
```

Interface :-

```
export interface Item {
  isbn: string;
  title: string;
  sector: string;
  pubdate: string;
  itemtype: string;
```

}

and i logged the dataSource and this is it.

[image]

Comment: How did you insert DisplayAllitemsComponent on other component? If you look at the Elements tab of dev tools, are the table structure with the bindings inserted in the DOM?

Comment: What did you mean by "How did you insert DisplayAllItemsComponent on other component " ?

Comment: I mean how did you use it on parent component, like how did you insert the selector of the component, and if is there any bindings or structural directives that may cause the entire component not to be shown.

Comment: Did you managed to fix it?